I have seen Patty Mayo He seems to be a Bail enforcement. Is he allowed to Take contents out of people's fridges Such as a Coke a cola
I ask because he seems to be doing it a lot recently in a lot of his videos. Patty Mayo is a youtuber on YouTube, he does bail. Enforcement And takes people to jail. And I just want to know if he's allowed to take people's things out of a fridge like food or a drink.

Paddy Mayo's content is fictional.
According to this page on legit.ng:

His thrilling Dutchberry Sheriffs Office (DBSO) show in the fictional Central Oregon town has made Mayo's channel one of the world's most famous bounty-hunting YouTube channels.
DBSO is unscripted and solely for entertainment. Nonetheless, the storylines are purely fictional, and the scenarios are staged. The actors, not real police officers, improvise actions and dialogue to create unpredictability. Also, they engage in intense chases, confrontations, and stunts that sometimes cause injuries. The stunts can be dangerous and shouldn't be recreated or reenacted at home.

As such, all the actors that appear on the show would have consented to have "their" belongings taken as a part of the show, so it is unlikely any actual crimes have been committed, even if crimes may have been depicted.
This is backed up by a statement by Oregon State Sherriffs Association stating that he and everyone else appearing in his videos are actors, and they are in no way associated with him.
